# "can not find symbol: FLASH_MODE_TORCH" Why android studio always throw out this error?

Tags: android, flash, sdk

```
          Camera cam ;      
          Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
          p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
```

I use sdk 5( for android 2.2 )to compile and the compllier thorw out this error.

thanks a lot

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I am using Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();

Then if I try to use p.

setflashmode doesn't show after input  (in android studio)
instead it shows p.setPictureSize().. etc

I already put minSDK=5   in my AndroidMainifest.xml

Comment: Check that `Parameters` is actually `Camera.Parameters`. Also post your error message.

Comment: post errors you are getting.

Comment: I am using     Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();

Comment: Then if I try to use p. 
setflashmode doesn't show instead it shows p.setPictureSize().. etc

Comment: I already put     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5"></uses-sdk> in my AndroidMainifest.xml